# cannot import name 'TypedDict' from 'pandas._typing'

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-styles

I want to apply some basic Table Visualisation as explained here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Styler-Object-and-HTML

For example with:

```
def highlight_max(s):
    if s.dtype == np.object:
        is_neg = [False for _ in range(s.shape[0])]
    else:
        is_neg = s < 0
    return ['color: red;' if cell else 'color:black' 
            for cell in is_neg]
# Using apply method of style 
# attribute of Pandas DataFrame
df.style.apply(highlight_max)
```

But keep getting this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'TypedDict' from 'pandas._typing' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_typing.py)
```

**Versions:**
pandas v1.2.0
python 3.9
jupyter-notebook : 6.2.0
jupyter core: 4.7.1

Comment: Cannot reproduce this issue. Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a complete code block which can be run in a clean workspace and reproduce the error?